# NSString drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode: thread safety

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, multithreading, uikit

I need to render some text to context in the background thread. Now I am using [NSString drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:] method to render it in the main thread. But I've read that I cannot use this method in the background thread. Could you help me?
P.S. my minimal

Comment: "Ok, but I've read here, that "UIStringDrawing methods are only safe to use from the main queue on iOS 6". You are right, [there is a known bug about this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12870371/335858). I deleted my answer because I did not know about that bug.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally advicable to do UI operations in foreground.Since UIKit is not thread safe. Check this post -->[performing drawRect in background thread and sizeWithFont using NSOperationQueue crashes app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968632/performing-drawrect-in-background-thread-and-sizewithfont-using-nsoperationqueue)